# Matplotlib time series missing part of the data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dict (**"groups_dict"**) of 3 pandas dataframes with the following attributes:

```
print(groups_dict['high'].info())
print(groups_dict['medium'].info())
print(groups_dict['low'].info())

# OUTPUT
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1241 entries, 0 to 1240
Data columns (total 2 columns):
date    1241 non-null datetime64[ns]
ppg     1241 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1)
memory usage: 19.5 KB

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1238 entries, 0 to 1237
Data columns (total 2 columns):
date    1238 non-null datetime64[ns]
ppg     1238 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1)
memory usage: 19.4 KB

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1179 entries, 0 to 1178
Data columns (total 2 columns):
date    1179 non-null datetime64[ns]
ppg     1179 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1)
memory usage: 18.5 KB
```

I have written the following script to plot a time series scatter plot of each of the 3 dataframes:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(15,15))
for ax, key in zip(axs, groups_dict.keys()):
    df = groups_dict[key]
    ax.scatter(df.index, df.ppg, s=5, alpha=0.5)
    ax.set_title(f"{key} quality")
    ax.set_ylabel('price per gram ($)')
    ax.set_xlabel('date')
    ax.set_xticklabels([dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') for dt in df.date], rotation=0)
```

See output here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU9yX.png

The issue is that I cannot get the dates to show up correctly on the x-axis. If I print the min/max dates in each dataframe, I see that there is actually a much wider range of dates than those represented on the plots above.

```
for key, df in groups_dict.items():
    print("df name:",key)
    print("min date:", df.date.min())
    print("max date:", df.date.max(),'\n')

# OUTPUT
df name: high
min date: 2010-09-02 00:00:00
max date: 2014-05-13 00:00:00 

df name: low
min date: 2010-09-02 00:00:00
max date: 2014-05-13 00:00:00 

df name: medium
min date: 2010-09-02 00:00:00
max date: 2014-05-13 00:00:00
```

As a check to make sure I am passing ax.set_xticklabels() the correct number of uniques:

```
for d in groups_dict.values():
    xtickarg = len(set([dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') for dt in d.date.tolist()]))
    print(d.shape[0], "==", xtickarg)

# OUTPUT
1241 == 1241
1179 == 1179
1238 == 1238
```

**If anyone can provide insight as to why the xticklabels are not displaying properly, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: You have 7 ticks on the x axis, but you are trying to set more than 1000 labels to those 7 ticks. Still, because there are only 7 ticks available, not more than those 7 are shown.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Where did I declare there to only be 7 ticks?

Comment: You did not declare that anywhere, that's why matplotlib decided to put 7 ticks there. Depending on the size of the plot it might also decide differently of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 7 ticks on the x axis, but you are trying to set more than 1000 labels to those 7 ticks. Still, because there are only 7 ticks available, not more than those 7 are shown.

It would probably make sense to directly plot the dates, something like

```
import matplotlib.dates 

dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(d.date.tolist())
ax.scatter(dates, df.ppg, s=5, alpha=0.5)
```

then use some useful ticker, e.g. a MonthLocator:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator())
```